why am I getting error in verce deployment?
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at parse (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/micromatch/index.js:15:6313)
at picomatch.makeRe (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/micromatch/index.js:15:21670)
at picomatch (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/micromatch/index.js:15:19637)
at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/micromatch/index.js:15:19294
at Array.map ()
at picomatch (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/micromatch/index.js:15:19286)
at micromatch.isMatch (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/micromatch/index.js:15:1090)
at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/collect-build-traces.js:244:48
at shouldIgnore (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/collect-build-traces.js:75:9)
at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/collect-build-traces.js:86:23
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
somebody help me with this its building in my pc but not working on vercel

Without code, it is impossible. Please provide more context...
